# CSS background position is not working

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

I have this code here...

```
.madactive{background: url(/graphics/madarrow.jpg) no-repeat center top 20px !important;}
```

But the image does not appear anymore, I inspected the element and the css is crossed out...

What I am trying to do is put a top on my background image.

What Am i doing wrong?

Comment: what's the `20px` for? You are defining a position of `center top`

Answer (score 5):

You have too many arguments in your declaration value. Either one of the following will work, depending on your specific needs:

```
.madactive{background: url(/graphics/madarrow.jpg) no-repeat center top !important;}
```

or

```
.madactive{background: url(/graphics/madarrow.jpg) no-repeat center 20px !important;}
```